# Javascript accordion function won't run?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to writing Javascript so I'm trying to write my own simple accordion function. I'm trying to make it so when I click on h2 it shows the "accordion-#" div. If the accordion is already open ("display=block"), I want to hide it ("display=none"). When I click on h2, nothing happens. I searched everywhere but I don't see what's wrong with my code:

```
function initiate(i) {
    var selected = document.getElementById('accordion-'+i).style.display;
    if(selected == "block") {
        selected = "none";
    } else {
    selected = "block";
    }
}
```

Sample HTML

```
<h2 onClick="initiate('6')">Project</h2>
<!-- begin code to hide/show -->
<div id="accordion-6" class="accordion">
    <div class="left">
         <p>left column text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
         <p>right column text</p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end code to hide/show -->
```

Sample CSS

```
main {
  margin: auto;
  width: 660px; }

main .accordion {
    padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    overflow: auto; }

main .accordion .left {
  width: 200px;
  float: left; }

main .accordion .right {
  width: 420px;
  float: right; }

#accordion-0 {
  display: block; }

#accordion-1 {
  display: block; }

#accordion-2 {
  display: block; }

#accordion-3 {
  display: block; }

#accordion-4 {
  display: block; }

#accordion-5 {
  display: block; }

#accordion-6 {
  display: block; }

#accordion-7 {
  display: block; }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things - first, the variable "selected" that you're creating is not what you think; it's not an object that you can change to target the source element's style property. It's a string storing what that property's value is. To accomplish what you want, you would store the element as a var and then use ".style.display=" to change it. Something like this:

```
var TargetDiv = document.getElementById('accordion-'+i);
    if(TargetDiv.style.display == "block" || TargetDiv.style.display == "") {
        TargetDiv.style.display = "none";
    } 
    else {
        TargetDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
```

The other change you'll see I made is your IF condition needs to also check for an empty style.display value; this is because even though you have it set to "block" via your CSS, the actual DIV has no "style" attribute on its markup and so style.display is empty at page load (i.e. when you first run the function against a given DIV).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c46qd/

Comment: I see now. My variable was just storing the display value as a string rather than creating an object out of the div box I'm trying to target. Makes sense now. I also see why you change the if statement. Thanks so much!